# Find current client (websocket)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am using something like the following code to save all clients in an array...

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080}),
CLIENTS=[];

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    CLIENTS.push(ws);
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        findClient(message);
    });
    ws.send("NEW USER JOINED");
});

function findClient (message) {
    for (var i=0; i<CLIENTS.length; i++) {
        //this is where I'm stuck
        if current client then return i
    } 
}
```

I do not know what to put inside the for loop to find the current client. I want to iterate through the array, and if the current client == one of the client in the array, I want to return its index.

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `findClient(ws)` -- you already have the ws (socket) belonging to that particular client bound to the closure of the message event handler. Then the `findClient` function becomes:

```
function getClientIndex(socket) {
  return CLIENTS.indexOf(socket);
}
```